# add any custom icon(mui icon or any other) instead of <img> apexcharts react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apexcharts

In apexcharts i'm working with customIcon[] ,  the customIcon takes object and its keys and values are like

```
customIcons: [
        {
          icon: '<img src="" width="15" />',
          class: "chart-icon",
          title: 'add anything',
          click: function () {
           function();
          },
        },
      ],
```

my Question is that i want to add icon from MUI icons instead of image tag below

```
"<img>"
```

there should be icon tag which is imported just like this and it should be working

```
import icon from "mui/material/icon"


customIcons: [
            {
              icon: '<icon />',
              class: "chart-icon",
              title: 'add title',
              click: function () {
                function ();
              },
            },
          ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use either

```
.logo {
   margin-top: 40px;
}
```

or

```
.logo {
   margin-bottom: -40px;
}
```

And change the px number depending on the height of your logo.

Comment: can you please write me the same navbar as given in picture?

Answer (score 0):

try

```css
.logo{
positision:relative;
top:40px
}
```